# How to get all the records whose updated date is less than 30 days in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get all the records from mysql database who have updated their records within 30 days from the current date for that i have used the below query but it is not working properly. $tda is the current date and $prevmonth is the date of exactly 
30 days back from the current date. Please help. Thanks.

```
$da=date('d');
$tda=date('d-m-Y');
$prevmonth = date(''.$da.'-m-Y', strtotime('-1 months'));
$sql_q=executeQuery("select * from ".reg." where 'uid' !=".$_SESSION['uid']." AND Updatedate >= '$prevmonth' AND  Updatedate <='$tda '");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in mysql as

```
`Updatedate` <  DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

OR

```
`Updatedate` <  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

For Varchar

```
 STR_TO_DATE(Updatedate, '%Y-%m-%d') <  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

UPDATE :

The query posted in the comment is wrong and should be

```
$sql_q=executeQuery("select * from registration
where 
`uid` != ".$_SESSION['uid']." 
AND STR_TO_DATE(Update_date, '%d-%m-%Y') < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)") ;
```

If you are looking for data within last 30 days then

```
$sql_q=executeQuery("select * from registration
where 
`uid` != ".$_SESSION['uid']." 
AND STR_TO_DATE(Update_date, '%d-%m-%Y') >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)") ;
```

Comment: Thanks.. I am using the following query but it is giving syntax error :view-individual-msg.php


$sql_q=executeQuery("select * from ".registration." where 'uid' !=".$_SESSION['uid']." AND STR_TO_DATE(Update_date, '%d-%m-%Y') <  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) '");

Comment: I'm happy that you found an answer. However, should your database grow to a decent size, that kind of WHERE clause will not scale happily. As @Andris brusquely said elsewhere, it would be more than wise to change those to datetime types so you don't have to "hide" them within a function.

Answer (score 1):

I like doing something like this: `AND UpdateDate > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND UpdateDate < NOW()`.

Answer (score 1):

If your `Updatedate` column is a `DATETIME` column then you can do the following:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE uid <> ?
AND Updatedate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND Updatedate <= NOW();
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE uid <> ?
AND Updatedate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND NOW();
```

Or if it's a timestamp then this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE uid <> ?
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(Updatedate) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(Updatedate) <= NOW();
```

Comment: Thanks..but my date time column is varchar

Comment: So how can achieve this when my date column is varchar.

Comment: Why are you storing your dates and times in a VARCHAR column?! Convert it to a data type that is meant to hold those types of values. Apart from the fact that what you have is just daft, you're making your task close to impossible.