# Query to retrieve records that are updated within 30 days not working properly in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to get all the records from mysql database which have been updated recently i.e. within 30 days. I have varchar field in database for that and using the below query but it shows all the records from the database. Please help

```
$sql_q=executeQuery("select * from registration
where 
`uid` != ".$_SESSION['uid']." 
AND STR_TO_DATE(Update_date, '%d-%m-%Y') < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)")
```

Comment: if within 30 days then change `STR_TO_DATE(Update_date, '%d-%m-%Y') < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)` to `STR_TO_DATE(Update_date, '%d-%m-%Y') >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)`

Comment: good atlast it worked :-)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, why not write an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: I already have answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984281/how-to-get-all-the-records-whose-updated-date-is-less-than-30-days-in-php/22984404#22984404

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to convert to string. Just use this

```
$sql_q=executeQuery("select * from registration
where 
`uid` != ".$_SESSION['uid']." 
AND Update_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)")
```

Comment: I think its the same one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984281/how-to-get-all-the-records-whose-updated-date-is-less-than-30-days-in-php/22984404#22984404 he is using varchar for date.